# Peewee reuse model class

Tags: python, database, sqlite, peewee

I have a peewee model class defined in `a.py` as

db = ...
class Foo(Model):
class Meta:
database = db

I am using `Foo` in file `b.py`. Presumably, all the top-level (non-class) code from `b.py` runs when I run `a.py` which uses `Foo`.

Question: who closes the database and where? Also, how do I decouple entity classes from the database reference? It seems like *really* bad design to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question what you are asking for help with. peewee models are normal python objects and follow the expected rules for importing them or sharing them across modules. So there is nothing special about Peewee models in that regard.

> who closes the database and where?

Presumably your code has an entry-point and a point at which it stops using the db. A command-line/GUI script can close the db before exiting. A web app would open the db conn at the start of a request and close it once the response is generated (a connection pool can be used).

> how do I decouple entity classes from the database reference

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database